# Why does / matches /something?

Tags: php, regex

I just noticed a bug in my app.

In my table, I store regular expression patterns and match them with an input.

In the table, I have '/' pattern (it was test data) stored.

to use '/' in php, I have the following code

```
$input = '/something';
$pattern = '/'.str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern).'/';
preg_match($pattern, $input, $matches);
```

why do I get a match in this case? How do I prevent it?

Comment: Why `str_replace` and `preg_match` unless I'm missing something one of them would be able to do it.

Comment: @Script47// Because I can't just put '/' as a part of regular expression. I have to escape it.

Comment: The code as posted doesn't make sense (and wouldn't work). Do you mean to use `$pattern` as the first arg to `preg_match()`?

Comment: Is `str_replace` being used instead of `preg_quote`? `$pattern` should be `$input` too right, on `str_replace`? You also could just change your delimiter then `/` doesnt need to be escaped; http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php.

Comment: You wonder why your regex to match a single `/` matches a `/` inside `/something`? It is logical, isn't it?

Comment: @chris85 // Thank you for preg_quote. I didn't even know it's there.

Comment: @stribizhev // I didn't know preg_match looks for substrings as per John Kugelman's answer.

Comment: `preg_quote` will turn the regex into a literal string. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Won't it be the same just that the delimiters and any special chars will be escaped? Which is what that `str_replace` is doing, unless I'm misreading it..

Comment: If you plan to match a *whole* string against some regex, use unambiguous `'/\A' . ... . '\z/'`.

Comment: If I read the question right, the OP wants to do regex matches, not literal string matches. `preg_quote` would turn the user-entered regexes into literal strings, effectively. Moon can correct me if I misunderstand.

Comment: @JohnKugelman // You're correct on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match` looks for substrings. If you want to match the whole string you'll need to anchor it with `^` and `$`. Perhaps:

```
$pattern = '/^(?:'.str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern).')$/';
```

`^` and `$` anchor the match, grouping with `()` makes sure any `|`s in the regex aren't misinterpreted, and `?:` keeps the group from adding an entry to `$matches`.

By the way, suggestions to change the delimiter to something else are missing the point: you have to have some sort of delimiter, and that delimiter needs to be escaped. If you switched `/` to `!` then you'd have trouble with `!` instead. It wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. Pattern can contain a lot of different things. It's like always escaping inserted data in SQL queries - you just Must always do it, no matter what. Same thing here - if your pattern contains, like, `(` or `)` - it will fail too. The only correct way that gives 100% result is using `preg_quote()`, which was created specifically for this case.

Comment: As I stated in comments above, `preg_quote()` would not do what the OP wants. It would neutralize all of the special regex chars, which is precisely what the OP does not want to have happen.

Answer (score -1):

You get the match because you are basically looking for `/` substring in `\/` string.
It is there. So you get a match.
I recommend replacing the pattern opening and ending tags to, say, `!`, to avoid any problems with `/` character. So, try this one:

```
preg_replace('!'.$pattern.'!', $input, $matches);
```

Or, if you want to escape the pattern no matter what, just use `preg_quote()`:

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($pattern, '/').'/', $input, $matches);
```

Comment: Just tested out preg_quote. It does't actually quote '/'

Comment: Try with the second parameter